# How do I set the default test command for `npm init`?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-init

I know I can do:

```
npm config set init.author.email me@mycompany.com
npm config set init.license UNLICENSED
```

To set the defaults used to create a new `package.json` with `npm init`. But how can I set the default value for the `test command`? I've tried

```
npm config set init.scripts.test "mocha"
```

But it doesn't work. The [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config) don't seem to help.

Is there a list of all the init defaults?

Comment: I think it will automatically ask you what's the test when running `init`

Comment: @zcui93 Yes, that's why I'm asking how to set the default: I'm tired of being asked.

Comment: what do you mean set default init? comman to run test through npm ?

Comment: @The I mean the default 'test command' for when you run `npm init`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a list of all config defaults `npm config list -l`.

As you can see there isn't anything like init.scripts. But there is another way to do it. If you first `npm install mocha` and then `npm init` you will get a package.json like:

```
{
  "name": "asd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^2.4.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED"
}
```

Comment: mocha is already installed in the parent module (and I don't want another copy) but if 'there isn't a way to set the default' is the answer then so be it.

Answer (score 4):

Although you can't (currently) configure default scripts via npm settings, you *can* customise the entire `npm init` output by providing your own [init-module](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#init-module). The default is stored at `~/.npm-init.js` - whatever you export becomes the result of running `npm init`.

To make this useful, you'd probably want to hijack the existing default npm init module, which lives in `<your npm install directory>/node_modules/init.js`. If you only care about providing a default test script, the simplest option is to use [init-module](https://github.com/ungoldman/init-module), which provides a configuration parameter `init-scripts-test`.

Comment: init-module looks like the way to go here. Good answer.

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for a way to programmatically create a `package.json` with dynamically defined values. I noticed creating a `package.json` file before calling `npm init -y` works as expected.

```js
// Require: fs
const fs = require('fs')

// Variables
const values = {
    "scripts": {
        "test": "mocha"
    }
    // as well as any other values you want
}

// Create package.json
fs.writeFileSync('package.json', values)
```

Running `npm init -y` after running the above code would generate a `package.json` with `scripts.test = "mocha"` defined.

If you're looking for a way to run `npm init -y` from within code as well, I recommend using [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs): `shell.exec('npm init -y')`.

Answer (score 2):

`npm config set init ...` will create a default configuration for all future projects that will be initialized - if you want to just set a few values once - simply use a shellscript to write some values prior to `npm init` like so:

```
echo '{"version":"0.1.0","license":"UNLICENSED","private":true,"scripts":{"test":"npx jest"}}' > "./package.json" && npm init -y
```